# How do I see which database is running faster after making changes to my.cnf file?

Tags: mysql, performance, phpmyadmin

**Background**

I have 5 servers all running essentially the same site but I have had difficulties with database speed. Part of the process has lead me to make changes to one of my my.cnf files to improve performance.

**Problem**

I am having difficulty finding if the settings are making any difference at all. I restart the mysql service and ever have rebooted the entire server, the variables show up as changed but I don't see any kind of noticeable difference when accessing my site. I would like a way to quantify how fast my database is without relying on the front end of the app so I can show my boss real figures for database speed instead of looking at the google console for load speeds.

**Research**

I thought that there might be some tool in phpmyadmin to help track speed but after going through the different tabs I couldn't find anything. All of the other on-line resources I have looked at seem to just talk about "expected results" instead of how to test directly.

**Question**

Is there a way to get speed information directly from the database (or phpmyadmin) instead of using the front end of the web app?

Comment: jam profiling information into a table directly from the app (datetime column using now()  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **optimal realistic benchmark** goes something like this:

1. Capture a copy of the live dataset.
2. Turn on the general log.
3. Run for some period of time (say, an hour).
4. Turn off the general log.

That gives you 2 things:  a starting point, and a list of realistic instructions.  Now to replay:

1. Load the data on a test machine.
2. Change some my.cnf setting.
3. Apply the captured general log, timing how long it takes.

Replay with another setting change; see if the timing is more than trivially faster or slower.

Even better would be to arrange for the replay to be multi-threaded like the real product.

Caveat...  Some settings won't make any difference until the size of something (data, index, number of connections, etc) exceeds some threshold.  Only at that point will the setting show a difference.  This benchmark method fails to predict such.

If you would like an **independent review of your my.cnf**, please provide these:

- How much RAM do you have
- SHOW VARIABLES;
- SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  -- after mysld has been running at least a day.

I will compute a couple hundred formulas and judge which ones are red flags.